# As Easy As A-B-C

Tags: code-golf, string, set-theory

## Input

A string that contains at most one of each of the letters `A`, `B`, and `C`. They may be in any order. The empty string is valid input.

<sup>**Note:** A previous version of this challenge used the letters `LEJ` instead of `ABC` and they may still be used if desired.</sup>

## Output

A string of the `A`, `B`, `C` letters that were not present in the input. They may be in any order.

If the output would be the empty string then simply giving no output is valid, if that makes sense for your implementation. (e.g. you don't need to actually call `print` on an empty string.)

## Examples

- If the input is `B` then the output should either be `CA` or `AC` since `A` and `C` are not present in the input.
- If the input is the empty string then the output should be `ABC` or any permutation since none of the three letters are present in the input.
- If the input is `CAB` then the output should be the empty string because all three letters are present in the input.

## Test Cases

There are so few input cases that we can enumerate all of them:

```
in -> out1 | out2 | out3 | ...
ABC -> ""
ACB -> ""
BCA -> ""
BAC -> ""
CAB -> ""
CBA -> ""
AB -> C
AC -> B
BC -> A
BA -> C
CA -> B
CB -> A
A -> BC | CB
B -> CA | AC
C -> AB | BA
"" -> ABC | ACB | BCA | BAC | CAB | CBA
```

All valid outputs for each input are given, separated by `|`'s. `""` represents the empty string

## Scoring

The shortest code in bytes wins. But keep in mind that you may get more recognition for solving the challenge in a [unique](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list) way rather than in a short way ;)

Comment: Is a list of characters acceptable for output, or must it be a string?

Comment: @Mego It must be a string (or be displayed as a string by default).

Comment: [Cumbersome I/O format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/45941)

Comment: @Mego It doesn't seem that cumbersome considering the difficulty of the task and shortness of the string.

Comment: The task is set difference between a constant and an input. Requiring that everything be done in strings is cumbersome with regards to the difficulty of the actual task.

Comment: In fact, since the challenge is really just set difference between a constant and an input, it's a dupe of [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34352/45941).

Comment: I vaguely remember a more exact dupe match where you had to subtract the input from a constant set.

Comment: @xnor That's the best one I could find. If you find a better dupe target, feel free to change it.

Comment: @xnor Any chance you're thinking of [Helka's recent challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107937/8478)?

Comment: @MartinEnder No, I remember it as being from a while ago.

Comment: Can inputs contain letters outside of "ABC"? The specification: "A string that contains at most one of each of the letters A, B, and C" does not exclude such inputs.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73828/34388)

Comment: Do you have to output all combinations or were you just showing all possible outputs separated by "|" ?

Comment: @theonlygusti The input should only contain ABC

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw "All valid outputs for each input are given, separated by |'s."

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85737/which-ghosts-are-missing)

Answer (score 20):

## Python 3, <s>29</s> <s>27</s> 22 bytes

```
lambda x:{*"ABC"}-{*x}
```

-2 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

-5 bytes thanks to Rod

Comment: `print(*{*"LEJ"}-{*input()})` saves 2. (tested on 3.5 and 3.6).

Comment: [You can also turn into a lambda for -5 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQYVWtpeTj6qVUq1utVVH7Py2/SCFTITNPIbUsMUcjM6@gtERDU9OKi7OgKDOvRCNNI1NT83@0OlCHuo66j5crkHT18gGRPiARLx@QiJcrSATMBIuCFYPFwErBusB6QBwgVo8FAA "Python 3 – TIO Nexus")

Comment: I love python ❤️

Comment: @theonlygusti Whatever happened to <3 and ♥?

Comment: @theonlygusti : I would love python if I can replace lamda with [](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda)

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

Thanks to @DuctrTape for the prod about the change and the presence of "ABC" in Jelly's dictionary.

```
“ḃ»ḟ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYc7DHc2Hdj/cMf9/uHU0kKtr96hhbqz14fZwFa7D7Y@a1rj//x@t7ujkrK6j7ujsBCSdnB1BpCNIxNkRJOLsBBIBM8GiYMVgMbBSsC6wHhAHiNVjAQ)**

`“ḃ»` looks up the entry "ABC" in Jelly's dictionary, `ḟ` is the filer discard dyad which discards the characters found in the input from that list of characters. The result is implicitly printed.

---

For a lower case version the dictionary entry to use can be either of "abac" (`“c»`) or "abaca" (`“i»`).

---

When the challenge was "LEJ" only **6** bytes could be achieved in the upper case variant, since no dictionary entries exist with that set of characters, leaving us to create the list of characters `“LEJ”` (or a permutation thereof).

The lowercase variant faired better at **5** bytes due to the presence of the word "jell" (`“ẎṄ»`).

Comment: I like how most of the code just generates the string "ABC", and the actual program itself is one character.  Classic jelly.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

Saved 2 bytes using the new `žR` command as suggested by *Kevin Cruijssen*

```
žRsм
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L6g4gt7/v93cgYA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X90X9DhZY@a1hydfHrO4ZVllS72SgqP2iYpKNmDpIov7Pmv8x8A)

**Explanation**

```
   м  # remove the character of
  s   # the input
žR    # from the string "ABC"
```

Comment: Shouldn't an input of only `J` return `EL, LE`?

Comment: Nice! Just as an FYI, inputs can also be represented as `"""{input}"""`, which also works for empty strings :).

Comment: @carusocomputing: It can return either (in this case it returns `LE`).

Comment: @Adnan: Good point. Never used the triple-string input except with multiline input. Will have to remember that :)

Comment: I find it hard to believe there isn't a built in to push ABC that is less than 4 bytes. `•CÞ•h` is 5... `2ÝAè` is lowercase and still 4...

Comment: @carusocomputing: ABC or CAB could be pushed in 3 chars as for example `'±ì`, but it would be lowercase, so converting to uppercase it would still be 4 :(

Comment: [Can be 4 bytes now](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9W6WKvpPCobZKCkv3/o/uCii/s@a/zP1rJ0clZSUfJ0dkJSDo5O4JIR5CIsyNIxNkJJAJmgkXBisFiYKVgXWA9IA4QK8UCAA)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Thanks! Do you know if `žR` has been useful before?

Comment: @Emigna Tbh no. I think it was added because of this challenge perhaps, but I personally haven't used it before.

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 15 bytes

```bash
tr -d x$1<<<LEJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19SpKCbolChYmhjY@Pj6vX//38vVwA)

I'd like to omit the `x`, but then `tr -d` would be missing an argument when the input string was empty.  (The `x` doesn't do any harm, since there aren't any x's in the here-string LEJ.) I'd normally write `tr -d "$1"`, but doing it the way I did is one byte shorter than that.

Comment: I had the same thoughts - even with the quotes - immediately, too.

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 14 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
$
¶ABC
D`.
A1`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#FYrBDcAwEML@zJFKeUXqCEClrnFTdoAudiEvbJlrvtUD/0cZTy3wru4jtCATomEKFpGJJYaT8kiHsQE)

#### Explanation

```
$
¶ABC
```

Append a second line containing `ABC`.

```
D`.
```

Deduplicate the characters. This deletes every character from the second line which already appears in the first line.

```
A1`
```

Discard the first line.

Comment: How exactly does the `1\`` part of the antigrep stage work?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Numbers in the configuration string are limits. `1` generally means "only do X once". How exactly limits work (i.e. what X is) depends on the stage type you're using. For antigrep stages, Retina first checks which lines match the regex (here, every line, since the regex is empty), but then the limit means "only discard the first matching line". Similarly, if it was a grep stage it would mean "only keep the first matching line". The semantics of all limits are listed [on the wiki](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language).

Answer (score 5):

## Java 7, <s>73</s> 58 bytes

```
String c(String s){return"EJL".replaceAll("[ "+s+"]","");}
```

15 bytes saved thanks to *@KritixiLithos*.

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/bHBU8m)

```
class M{
  static String c(String s){return"EJL".replaceAll("[ "+s+"]","");}

  public static void main(final String[] a) {
    System.out.print("LEJ=" + c("LEJ") + "; ");
    System.out.print("LJE=" + c("LJE") + "; ");
    System.out.print("EJL=" + c("EJL") + "; ");
    System.out.print("ELJ=" + c("ELJ") + "; ");
    System.out.print("JLE=" + c("JLE") + "; ");
    System.out.print("JEL=" + c("JEL") + "; ");
    System.out.print("LE=" + c("LE") + "; ");
    System.out.print("LJ=" + c("LJ") + "; ");
    System.out.print("EJ=" + c("EJ") + "; ");
    System.out.print("EL=" + c("EL") + "; ");
    System.out.print("JL=" + c("JL") + "; ");
    System.out.print("JE=" + c("JE") + "; ");
    System.out.print("L=" + c("L") + "; ");
    System.out.print("E=" + c("E") + "; ");
    System.out.print("J=" + c("J") + "; ");
    System.out.print("\"\"=" + c(""));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
LEJ=; LJE=; EJL=; ELJ=; JLE=; JEL=; LE=J; LJ=E; EJ=L; EL=J; JL=E; JE=L; L=EJ; E=JL; J=EL; ""=EJL
```

Comment: Can you do `"["+s+"]"` instead of `s.replaceAll("(.)","$1|")`?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Smart. It fails for the empty String, but by adding a space (or any other character that isn't `EJL`) it works again, which is still a lot shorter. :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 7 bytes

```
"LEJ"-Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@6/k4@qlpHtu8f//Sj5OSgA)

```
"LEJ"-Σ
"LEJ"    the letters
     -   exclude letters present in input
      Σ  concatenate
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
-"ABC
```

[Test it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-%22ABC&input=%22ab%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%27ABC%27%0A%27ACB%27%0A%27BCA%27%0A%27BAC%27%0A%27CAB%27%0A%27CBA%27%0A%27AB%27%0A%27AC%27%0A%27BC%27%0A%27BA%27%0A%27CA%27%0A%27CB%27%0A%27A%27%0A%27B%27%0A%27C%27%0A%27%27&debug=0)

Expands to

```
-"ABC"Q
-       # Filter on absence
 "ABC"  # Literal string 
      Q # Input
```

Comment: abc can be written as `<G3`

Comment: @Maltysen yeah [muddyfish](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110298/47120) used that, but it is lowercase anyway =\

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES6, <strike>41 39</strike> 38 Bytes

```js
s=>eval(`'ABC'.replace(/[${s}]/g,'')`)
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Arnauld.
Saved 1 bytes thanks to LarsW.

```js
f=s=>eval(`'ABC'.replace(/[${s}]/g,'')`)

console.log(f("AB"));
```

Comment: I'm on mobile, so I can't test my code, but this should work I think: `s=>eval\`'ABC'.replace(/[${s}]/g,'')\``

Comment: Nice work! Being able to say `.join\`\`` saves you two characters over the solution I had come up with: `f=s=>"ABC".replace(RegExp(\`[${s}]\`,'g'),"")` .

Comment: @LarsW That exact code didn't seem to work, but adding brackets around the template string did and saved one byte. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## MATL, <s>10</s> 8 bytes

Saved two bytes thanks to Suever. `setdiff` is shorter than `ismember`.

```
'ABC'iX-
```

[**Try it here!**](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%27ABC%27iX-&inputs=%27BA%27&version=19.7.4)

**Explanation**

```
'ABC'      % Create a string literal
     i     % User input
      X-   % Set difference, between two elements of the stack
```

Yes, this might have been a trivial task, but I'm quite satisfied I managed to solve it with MATL all by myself. <sub>I never said it was the shortest solution... Thanks Suever!</sub>

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 10 bytes

```
CLEJ<ESC>Ó[<C-r>"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@@/s4@olfXhytJBS7P//rj4A)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 434c 454a 1bd3 5b12 225d                 CLEJ..[."]
```

#### Explanation

Input is on the first line of the buffer. So something like:

```
EL
```

and the cursor is on the first character. So we delete the input (which stores it in register `"`) and enter insert mode simultaneously using `C`.

Once in insert mode, the characters `LEJ` are inserted, after which I return to normal mode using `<ESC>`.

Now we have to remove all the characters that are present in the input.

```
Ó                       " remove every
 [<C-r>"]               "  character that appears in the input
                        " synonym of Vim's :s/[<C-r>"]//g
```

And once this happens, we are left with the remaining letters in the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, <s>27 19</s> 18 bytes

```
->s{"ABC".tr s,""}
```

-1 byte thanks to Martin Ender

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
("ABC"\\)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@ZW5BfVKLgkliSqOeTWVzyPzcxM0/BViEzryS1KDG5REFDydHJWSkmRvO/kyMA) Usage: `("ABC"\\) "CB"` yields `"A"`.

`\\` is the set difference operator, the parenthesis form a so called *section* which is a short form for the lamda `(\x -> "ABC" \\ x)`.

---

**Without import:** (same byte count thanks to @nimi)

```hs
f x=[c|c<-"ABC",all(/=c)x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@mUGEbnVyTbKOr5OjkrKSTmJOjoW@brFkR@z83MTNPwVYhM68ktSgxuUQh7b@TIwA) Usage: `f "CB"` yields `"A"`.

---

Other approaches:

```hs
f x=filter(`notElem`x)"ABC"
(`filter`"ABC").flip notElem
f x=[c|c<-"ABC",notElem c x]
```

Comment: I hope `(\\)` will be moved to Prelude soon.

Comment: @theonlygusti I hope it won't; this isn't really a sensible operation _for lists_ (at least not unless you explicitly state you want list-as-set). The default operation for that task should be [`Data.Set.difference`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.1/docs/Data-Set.html#v:difference).

Comment: @ceasedtoturncounterclockwis why is it not sensible? Besides, the only reason I desire it moved is because it is useful, frequently.

Comment: @theonlygusti it's not sensible in the sense that if you find yourself using it, it's a sign that you're probably using the wrong data structure. Lists can have duplicate elements, an order, and they may be lazily constructed (even infinite). `(\\)` respects none of this. Data types that are _intended_ for this behaviour have a structure that makes them generally quite a bit more effecient, safer (because no possible stability etc. assumptions can be broken) and exposing a more comfortable interface.

Comment: @ceasedtoturncounterclockwis what, yes it does. "The first instance of..." but nvm

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 120 + 3 = 123 bytes

```
<>((((((((()()){}){}){}){}){}())())())<>{({}(<()>)){(([({})]<>({}))){(<({}<>{})<>([{}]{}<>)>)}{}}{}{}<>{}{({}<>)<>}{}}<>
```

It is run with the `-c` flag, adding 3 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#TYvRCcAwCETXOT@6gQidI@SrY4iz25eEQuVA73zXHvrGZJb1F8GRRwrrsoCRBs4mXdYKnAOmADWy5nKglYXOKzcCsEKP7ruv5wU)

### Explanation

Overall this program pretty much does the right stack set minus the left stack with the right stack initialized to `CBA` and the left stack initialized to the input.

#### Annotated Code

```
<>((((((((()()){}){}){}){}){}())())())<> # Switch to right stack, push CBA, switch back
{({}(<()>)){(([({})]<>({}))){(<({}<>{})<>([{}]{}<>)>)}{}}{}{}<>{}{({}<>)<>}{}}<>
```

*More explanation to come...*

Answer (score 3):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>34</s> 29 bytes

Includes +1 for `-r`

-5 thanks to [Digital Trauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma)

```
s/^/ABC/
:
s/(.)(.*)\1/\2/
t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#DckxDoAgEATAfl9BB5jIRUu7u/0GodIPiP/HbWfmc6f9TXlNG@ZBw4VppdXSttoP66fhW3lBB2cg6Agn6AGGy8VSoUwEPfgD)

For some reason TIO doesn't work with extended regex (`-r`), so I had to wrap it in BASH.

---

```
s/^/ABC/        # put ABC at the beginning of the string
:               # nameless label
s/(.)(.*)\1/\2/ # remove a duplicate letter
t               # branch to the nameless label if something changed
```

Comment: The newline, `-n` and `P` are unnecessary.  Also you can wrap this up in bash to get it to work in TIO.  No idea why `-r` doesn't work. https://tio.run/nexus/bash#DcmxDYAwDATA/qdIR4JELCjp7F8jooIFCPubb@/mc5ftLUtOu8yDhhPTam@1r23sNg7Dl0tCB2cg6Agn6AGGy8VSoUwEPZg/

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thanks! I was thinking there would be characters besides A, B, and C when I wrote this.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 37 bytes

```
Complement@@Characters@{"ABC",#}<>""&
```

Comment: Is there a reason you used strings here rather than lists of characters?

Comment: @GregMartin habit, I guess

Comment: just that I think it comes out shorter if you can avoid `Characters`

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>29</s> 27 bytes

Saved two bytes thanks to Suever, by creating the string `'ABC'`, inside the `ismember` call.

```
@(s)x(~ismember(x='ABC',s))
```

We use `~ismember()` as logical indices to the variable `x`. The peculiar thing is, we create `x='ABC'` *inside* `ismember`, not in front of it. The order Octave sees this:

```
@(s)                        % Anonymous function that takes a string s as input
                x='ABC'     % Create a variable x with the characters 'ABC'
       ismember(x='ABC',s)  % True for elements that are in both x and s. False otherwise.
      ~ismember(x='ABC',s)  % Negate this, so that we keep the characters that aren't in s
@(s)x(~ismember(x='ABC',s)) % Use the logical vector as indices to x and return the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Carrot](https://github.com/kritixilithos/Carrot), 15 bytes

*I found a bug with returning matches and empty strings. So I just fixed it*

```
ABC^//[^#]/gS""
```

[Try it online!](http://kritixilithos.github.io/Carrot/) (copy & paste)

#### Explanation

```
ABC^                   //sets stack (just a string, not an array) to "ABC"
    /                  //return match(es) of:
     /[^#]/g           // `#` is the placeholder for the input
                       // so effectively, this returns the matches of any character not present in the input
                       // applied on the stack
                       //this returns an array of all the matches of the regex
            S""        //join all the elements of the array using "", the empty string
```

Answer (score 2):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
"ABC"l-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#K/TTr7bysf6v5OjkrOSj@z82r1b/P5cjl7Mjl5OjMwA) (As a linefeed-separated test suite.)

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB / Octave, 20 bytes

```
@(x)setdiff('ABC',x)
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/6S3TMi)

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <strike>50 Bytes</strike> <strike>32 Bytes</strike> <strike>47 Bytes</strike> 35 Bytes

where `i` is the input:

```
i=>string.Join("","ABC".Except(i));
```

**Full app tested in LINQPad**

```
void Main()
{
    var testcases = new Dictionary<string,string[]>
    {
        ["ABC"] = new[]{""},
        ["ACB"] = new[]{""},
        ["BCA"]  = new[]{""},
        ["BAC"]  = new[]{""},
        ["CAB"]  = new[]{""},
        ["CBA"]  = new[]{""},
        ["AB"] = new[]{"C"},
        ["AC"] = new[]{"B"},
        ["BC"] = new[]{"A"},
        ["BA"] = new[]{"C"},
        ["CA"] = new[]{"B"},
        ["CB"] = new[]{"A"},
        ["A"] = new[]{"BC","CB"},
        ["B"] = new[]{"CA","AC"},
        ["C"] = new[]{"AB","BA"},
        [""] = new[]{"ABC","ACB","BCA","BAC","CAB","CBA"},
    };
    
    var output = "";
    
    foreach(var input in testcases.Keys)
    {
        var expect = testcases[input];
        var actual = GetResult(input);
        if(!expect.Contains(actual)) throw new ApplicationException($"{input}:{string.Join(",",expect)}:{actual}");
        output+=$"{input} -> {actual}\n";
    }
    output.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
private string GetResult(string input){
    return string.Join("","ABC".Except(i));
}
```

**Test results**

> ABC ->
> ACB ->
> BCA ->
> BAC ->
> CAB ->
> CBA ->
> AB -> C
> AC -> B
> BC -> A
> BA -> C
> CA -> B
> CB -> A
> A -> BC
> B -> AC
> C -> AB
> -> ABC

Comment: That's not a valid answer, it has to be a function or a program, not a code snippet.

Comment: Ah. My bad. First timer here. So i need the print part in it?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon: You either need to make the entry into an entire program, which compiles (not recommended in C#, it has a lot of boilerplate), or into a function that can be called multiple times; at the moment it's just a statement. In C#, it's nearly always easiest to make it into a function by creating a lambda, that takes input via its arguments, and returns via its return value.

Comment: `string.Join("",...)` -> `string.Concat(...)` Saves 1 byte

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>13</strike> 12 bytes

```
"ABC"r"[{U}]
```

Saved a byte thanks to ETHproductions.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@6/k6OSsVKQUXR1aG/v/v5KjEgA)

Comment: Nice, thanks for using Japt! You can remove the trailing quote to save a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 7 bytes

```
'ABC'∘~
```

`~` is set subtraction, `∘` is compose, so this is a function that returns `ABC` minus the characters in its input.

Answer (score 1):

### [Jellyfish](https://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 9 bytes

```
PNI
 "ABC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jellyfish#@x/g58mloOTo5Pz/v6MTAA)

In more conventional notation, this program translates to:

```
P(N("ABC", I))
```

`I` is the input, `N` is list difference, and `P` is output.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5.9.9 <s>79 38 37</s> 35 bytes

```
perl -le '$_="ABC";eval"y/$ARGV[0]//d";print'
```

(not sure of the counting rules here - have included switches but not the perl command).

```
> perl -le '$_="ABC";eval"y/$ARGV[0]//d";print' AB
C
> perl -le '$_="ABC";eval"y/$ARGV[0]//d";print'
ABC
```

(adjusted counts after adjudication comment below)

Comment: Will that work for empty input?

Comment: Now I fixed the transcription error (had "..", typed {,,} here...)

Comment: Your code is 35 bytes long. (34 +1 for the `-l` flag). :)

Comment: Thanks. The -l is for prettification (as in a newline at the end of the output.). wasn't sure if that was necessary from the contest rules.

Comment: [With 5.14+](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Non-destructive-substitution), you can do `perl -pe'$_=eval"ABC=~y/$_//dr"'` for only 23 bytes (22 + 1 for `-p`).

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, 71 bytes

The largest entry at the moment, but at least it is readable ;-)

```
(lambda(s)(coerce(set-difference'(#\A #\B #\C)(coerce s'list))'string))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 4 bytes

```
-<G3
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-%3CG3&input=%22a%22&debug=0)

```
 <G3 -  alphabet[:3]
-    - input-^
```

Note this uses lower case which might not be acceptable

Answer (score 1):

## C, 53 bytes

```c
b=64;c(char*a){while(b<67)putchar(++b*!strchr(a,b));}
```

If implicit declarations of string.h are not allowed, **72 bytes**, to add `#include<string.h>`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#U87MS84pTUm1KS4pysxL18uw@59ka2ZinayRnJFYpJWoWV2ekZmTqpFkY2auWVBaAhLV0NZO0lIEakjOKNJI1EnS1LSu/Z@ZV6KQm5iZpwFiVOkogLVrVWoqVHMpKCgkayg5Kmlac9X@BwA)

---

or something a bit more fun at **75 bytes**

```c
a[128]={};b=64;c(char*d){while(*d)++a[*d++];while(b<67)putchar(b*!a[++b]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@58YbWhkEWtbXWudZGtmYp2skZyRWKSVolldnpGZk6oBZGlrJ0ZrpWhrx1pDhJJszMw1C0pLQAo1krQUE6O1tZNiNa1r/2fmlSjkJmbmaYAYVToKYKO0KjUVqrkUFBSSNZQcnZU0rblq/wMA)

Comment: [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/JOlkjM69EK1GzOi2/SCPJ1szEOsnGzNxaMzMvJbVCI1FHWztJs6amoAioKk1DLUnTuvY/kKmQm5iZB9KpUKWjkJyRWKSlVampUM2loKCQrKHkqKRpzVX7HwA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 101 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@for %%c in (L E J)do @call set d=%%s:%%c=%%&call:c %%c
:c
@if "%d%"=="%s%" set/pd=%1<nul
```

Takes input on STDIN, which means that `%1` is empty when the code falls through into the helper subroutine and nothing gets printed.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>47</s> 40 bytes

```r
gsub(paste0("[",scan(,""),"]"),"","ABC")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P724NEmjILG4JNVAQylaSac4OTFPQ0dJSVNHKRZEKOkoOTo5K2n@V3d0Vv8PAA)

Replaces any letters in the input string with the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
‛ėġ⇧$F
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigJvEl8Sh4oenJEYiLCIiLCJBQiJd)

```
     F # Remove from...
‛ėġ⇧   # "ABC"
    $  # The input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 21 bytes

```
{'ABC'.trans($_=>"")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYs7CoAwEESvMizBD4illQns7kGChan8EW1EPXvcat7wZo45L0NZb1QJvjw1i9b9laftbFz0gaj9yjndIBfhA54EFz9C2jOIOryjHcAqEGUIK5QFKgwLayaNTdnCPDSUHw)

Transliterates all of the characters in the input string into the null string.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 41 bytes

```lua
print((('LEJ'):gsub('['..(...)..']',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge, <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```
~2p~2vv:<_>"C"-#v_@
8p2~p<>,0^g2::+1<*8
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=fjJwfjJ2djo8Xz4iQyItI3ZfQAo4cDJ+cDw+LDBeZzI6OisxPCo4&input=Qg)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```php
<?=preg_replace("([Z$argv[1]])","",ABC);
```

`Z` added to character class to work around `missing terminating ]`  warning for empty input.

no regex, **43 bytes**:

```php
<?=str_replace(str_split($argv[1]),"",ABC);
```

- `str_split` splits input to array of single characters
- `str_replace` replaces all occurences of each array element in `ABC` with the empty string

Comment: Regex like `"/[Z$argv[1]]/"` seems to work with empty input as well, and saves 3 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## VB.Net, 65 bytes

```
Sub F(s)
Console.Write(String.Join("","ABC".Except(s)))
End Sub
```

A subroutine (function) that takes the input string, and removes each character present in the input from the string "ABC". Then it joins the resulting characters back into a string, before printing them to the console.

Answer (score 0):

## Pure bash, 59 bytes

If the newline isn't necessary, removing the final "echo" takes it down to 54 bytes.

```
for i in A B C
{
[ X${1//$i/} = X$1 ] && echo -n $i
}
echo
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 39 bytes

```
#(apply str((group-by(set %)"ABC")nil))
```

Transforms input string into set of characters, and then uses it as a function by which it groups string "ABC". For example, if the input string is "B" then the result is `{nil [\A \C], \B [\B]}` and all we have to do is take value by key `nil` and convert it to string. Beats Common Lisp!

[See it online](http://ideone.com/hBoSqT)

Answer (score 0):

### Go, <s>158</s> <s>153</s> <s>151</s> 146 bytes

**condensed:**

```
package main;import(."os";."fmt");func main(){b:=[3]int{65,66,67};for _,e:=range Args[1]{b[e-65]=1};Print(string(b[0])+string(b[1])+string(b[2]))}
```

**uncondensed:**

```
package main

import (
    ."os"
    ."fmt"
)

func main() {
    //A,B,C are represented as 65,66,67 in int
    b := [3]int{65, 66, 67}
    //Loop through the ABC argument.
    for _,e := range Args[1]{
        //Find the letter that exists. If it's A then b[65-65] -> b[0] -> A
        //We replace the integer, with 1 which is equal to an empty string if converted.
        b[e-65] = 1
    }
    //Covert each int to string.
    Print(string(b[0])+string(b[1])+string(b[2]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 23 bytes

```
(s:String)=>"ABC"diff s
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica 38 Bytes

```
""<>Complement@@Characters/@{"ABC",#}&
```

splits out the characters of the input string and the string "ABC" and performs their complement and a shorthand StringJoin.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 61 bytes

```
<?=implode("",array_diff(["A","B","C"],str_split($argv[1])));
```

Answer (score 0):

## perl 5.18, 35 bytes

```
print"ABC"=~s/[@{[shift||" "]}]//gr
```

Examples:

```
perl -le'print"ABC"=~s/[@{[shift||" "]}]//gr' A        # BC
perl -le'print"ABC"=~s/[@{[shift||" "]}]//gr' BC       # A
perl -le'print"ABC"=~s/[@{[shift||" "]}]//gr'          # ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6, 38 bytes

```
say join "","ABC".split(get.split(""))
```

Example found in close to every "remove substring" answer.
EDIT: Fixed the mistake when AC it returns ABC

Comment: For input “AC” this outputs “ABC”… ☹

Comment: @manatwork holy cow, well.... I can acctually see how that is happening.. Darn finding a fix now

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 7 bytes

```
"abc"l-
```

Explanation:

```
"abc"l-
"abc"   e#Push ['a','b','c']
     l  e#Push input
      - e#Remove input from ['a','b','c']
        e#Implict output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 44 characters

```
\A=@set{r;ABC}
?=@set{r;@subst{?=;$r}}
\Z=$r
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ printf CB | gema '\A=@set{r;ABC};?=@set{r;@subst{?=;$r}};\Z=$r'
A
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 22 bytes

```bash
x=ABC
echo ${x//[$1]/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYopCTmZdqrZCSr1CcWqKgq6ugpAISUfpfYevo5MyVmpyRr6BSXaGvH61iGKtf@z8lPy/1P0jG2cmRy9EJSHE5cgEpLgA)

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 20 bytes

```sh
x=ABC
<<<${x//[$1]/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@ekZmTqlCUmpiikJOZl2qtkJKvUJxaoqCrq6CkAhJR@l9h6@jkzGVjY6NSXaGvH61iGKtf@z8lPy/1P0jc2cmRy9EJSHE5cgEpLgA)

Nothing crazy, just remove matches from the string "ABC"

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 7 bytes

```
"ABC"kU
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=IkFCQyJrVQ==&input=IkMi) | [Run the testcases](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=IkFCQyJrVQ==&input=WwoiQUJDIiwKIkFDQiIgCiJCQ0EiCiJCQUMiCiJDQUIiCiJDQkEiCiJBQiIKIkFDIgoiQkMiIAoiQkEiIAoiQ0EiCiJDQiIgCiJBIgoiQiIgCiJDIgoiIgpdCi1tUQ==)

---

As [Embodiment of Ignorance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84206/embodiment-of-ignorance) pointed out:

**6 bytes** if lowercase input/output is acceptable:

```
`¯b`kU
```

[Run it online](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=YK9iYGtV&input=ImFiIg==)

Comment: If lowercase is allowed, 6 bytes: https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=YK9iYGtV&input=ImFiIg==

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

Input & output as strings.

```
;3îB kU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=OzPuQiBrVQ==&input=IkEi)

Input & output as arrays of characters.

```
3õdI kU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=M/VkSSBrVQ==&input=WyJBIl0=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 16 bytes

Inspired by [Sean’s Raku answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/253182/11261).

```ruby
$_="ABC".tr$_,""
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnm0km5BjlLsgqWlJWm6FhtU4m2VHJ2clfRKilTidZSUIMJQ2QUrgFJczo5cThA-AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ʋABCḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT0lQ0ElOEJBQkMlRTElQjglOEQmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD1BQkMlMEFBQ0IlMEFCQ0ElMEFCQUMlMEFDQUIlMEFDQkElMEFBQiUwQUFDJTBBQkMlMEFCQSUwQUNBJTBBQ0IlMEFBJTBBQiUwQUMlMEElMjIlMjImZmxhZ3M9Vg==)

##### Explanation

```python
ʋABCḍ  # Implicit input
ʋABC   # Push "ABC"
    ḍ  # Symmetric set difference
       # Implicit output
```